# How does a person create a section group hierarchy in OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I can create a new section fine in OneNote.

I can create a new page fine in OneNote.

I am wondering how I create a new section group?

It seems to be a bit obscure ..

Online help mentions Ctrl+Shift+G and Shift+f10, these didn't seem to work for me.

Ah - I think I have worked it out:

I have to right click the "+ Add section" button (bottom left) ..

That's not so easy to work out and find !

I wonder why they (MS) removed this function/option from the right click menu options as per previously documented in older MS doco ?  I see there is a "feedback" option to MS .. I will suggest that option for add new section group be put back in the right click options.

See this image on how to do this:

Is there any other way to create section groups ?
Maybe usage of section groups is being discouraged ?

Answer (score 0):

In OneNote which comes with the latest Office 365, the function is on context menu of any section tab:

[image: enter code here]

Similarly, I can select the command using keyboard sequence:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (focuses current section tab)
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> (opens context menu), or just single press of [menu key a.k.a. <kbd>AppsKey</kbd>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key)
3. <kbd>G</kbd> (selects item *New Section Group* – see underlined **G** on the above image)